# Unable to import components into storybook

Tags: javascript, typescript, storybook

I am having trouble getting my first storybook to work. I am using the latest storybook version and configuration, and ran `npx sb init` to do so, as documented [here](https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/get-started/install).

The following story file will run fine:

**SampleComponent.stories.tsx:**

```js
import React from 'react';
// eslint-disable-next-line import/no-extraneous-dependencies
import { Meta } from '@storybook/react/types-6-0';
// eslint-disable-next-line import/no-extraneous-dependencies
import SampleComponent from './SampleComponent';

export const Foo: React.FC = () => <SampleComponent />;

export default {
  title: 'Testing',
  component: Foo,
} as Meta;
```

however, the following storybook does not work and I get an empty storybook instead. I also get the console message:

> Found a story file for "Testing" but no exported stories.

**SampleComponent.stories.tsx:**

```js
import React from 'react';
// eslint-disable-next-line import/no-extraneous-dependencies
import { Meta } from '@storybook/react/types-6-0';
// eslint-disable-next-line import/no-extraneous-dependencies
import SampleComponent from './SampleComponent';

export default {
  title: 'Testing',
  component: SampleComponent,
} as Meta;
```

Why am I not able to import the `SampleComponent` directly into my default export?

---

**.storybook/main.js:**

```js
module.exports = {
  "stories": [
    "../src/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)"
  ],
  "addons": [
    "@storybook/addon-links",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials"
  ]
}
```

**SampleComponent.tsx:**

```
import React from 'react';

const SampleComponent: React.FC = () => <h1>Hello World</h1>;

export default SampleComponent;
```

**file strcuture:**

```
src/
  - components/
    - SampleComponent/
      - SampleComponent.tsx
      - SampleComponent.stories.tsx
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `stories` file should export stories, as named export. Your second example doesn't export any stories.

You can add :

```
export MyStory = () => <SampleComponent/>
```

or export directory `SampleComponent`, but it's probably not a good idea: you
will probably use args, parameters and others.